# MariaDB vs Mysql import through command line macosx

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

My channel website is using `mysql` but i use `XAMPP` on my mac,which from newer version uses `MariaDB` instead of `Mysql`.

I tried to import large database from my `cpanel` to my localhost via command line on my `mac`.

At one point the query stopped working and printed the error message that

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array
>   (
>       [type] => 1
>       [message] => Maximum execution time of 300 seconds e' at line 280
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

so i want to know is it a problem with 2 different versions or its execution time problem.

What should i do to increase the execution time in my `Xampp`?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked what is in the dump at the referenced row?

Comment: @shadow no i didn't. I can not open it in any editor because file is more than 8gb big. so is there a way to open it in command line and check the content?

Answer (score 0):

You could try altering the configuration to change `max_statement_time`. This assumes that you are on MariaDB 10.1.1 or later and that the execution time is the issue.

You may also wish to have a look at [Aborting Statements that Exceed a Certain Time to Execute](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/aborting-statements/)

Comment: i tried using this command but it throws error to check the manual. `SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=1000; SET autocommit=0 ; source /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/geo_live-2.sql ; COMMIT ;` Am i using it right??

Comment: Have a look at these links. I think comma separator between SET STATEMENT values. [Server System Variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#max_statement_time) and [SET STATEMENT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/set-statement/)

Comment: Personally I'd split into multiple steps doing parts at a time.

Comment: i tried this as well `SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=1000 FOR source /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/geo_staging.sql ;` same error.

Comment: From what I can see the SET STATMENT has to be in the actual source rather than telilng it where the source code is. That is you probably need to edit geo_staging.sql to include the SET STATEMENT.